# Multipart upload to S3 from an API

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a web API for text analytics backed by AWS S3. In order to allow clients to upload large (multi-MB or even multi-GB) files I have been looking at the S3 multipart upload facility. The endpoints to which clients upload belong to my API, and I never expose my use of S3 directly. My (perhaps naive) assumption is that, when a large file is submitted, I will first need to handle a multipart upload of files to my server, then do a second multipart upload from my server to S3. Does that sound right? Or some kind of redirect. Neither possibility sounds particularly efficient...

I mean DropBox presumably does something like this, given that they're backed by S3. I'm wondering whether using DropBox itself rather than the raw S3 API might be easier and faster?

Answer (score 0):

Your clients can upload large files intact through your API, and from there do multi-part upload to S3 for performance and to break the 5GB limit for single part uploads:

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_much_data_can_I_store

You can either send the multiple parts to S3 while the client is uploading to your service, or cache the whole thing, end the request, and ship it asynchronously.

The Dropbox application allows large files, but Dropbox limits the size of uploads through their web interface to 300MB:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/5/en